# delete Entity objects that reference another objects (foreign key relation tables)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

```
public void DeleteGenreList()
{
    var genreList = entities.Genres.AsEnumerable();

    foreach (var oneGenre in genreList)
    {

        foreach (var onesong in oneGenre.Songs)
        {
            entities.Songs.DeleteObject(onesong);
        }

        entities.Genres.DeleteObject(oneGenre);
    }
}
```

I can not delete my Genre object that contains song objects because i'm getting collection was modified error, pls help thx!

Answer (score 0):

This not foreign key relations problem, you cannot delete object which are processing in some loop.

You can use something like this:

```
var genreList = entities.Genres.ToList();

genreList.ForEach(x=>x.Songs.Clear());    
entities.Genres.Clear();
```

Comment: This doesnt work, there are no such methods as .clear or .foreach

Comment: @AlanBudzinski Use var genreList = entities.Genres.ToList();

Comment: ok so I have added the .ToList() and my code look like this:              public void DeleteGenreList()
        {

            var genreList = entities.Genres.ToList();

            genreList.ForEach(x => x.Songs.Clear());
            entities.Genres.ToList().Clear();
        }

Comment: But i get new error: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a collection while you enumerate through it using a  For Each loop.

This should work:

```
for (int i=0;i<entities.Songs.Count;i++)
{
       entities.Songs.DeleteObject(entities.Songs[i]);
       i--;
}
```

Comment: Where is `onesong` set? Also `i++` and `i--` is not necessary. A cleaner solution for your approach would be `while(entities.Songs.Count>0) { entities.Songs.DeleteObject(entities.Songs[0]); }`

Comment: it should be entities.Songs[i] instead of onesong. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

if the relationship between Genre and song is marked as Cascade delete ( in the model mapping and database), then you should just be able to delete Genre and EF would take care of deleting songs ...